# Using an int arraylist for simple addition

Tags: android, arraylist

Working with Eclipse for an Android app, I have declared and populated an integer array:

`ArrayList<Integer> ptAr = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

I have it populated with integers, which I verified.  Now I am trying to loop through the array and use the values for simple addition.  I have tried the following (among many other things):

```
sum += ptAr.get(i) 
sum += Integer.valueOf(ptAr.get(i))
sum += ptAr.indexOf(i)
sum += Integer.valueOf(ptAr.indexOf(i));
```

Every one of the above crashes.  This seems like it should be extremely simple; what am I missing?

Comment: initial value of sum.?

Comment: ArrayList.get(index) will return you the value in arraylist , could you post more about your error ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through your list, you can use a for-each loop as shown below.

```
    for (Integer integer : ptAr) {
        sum += integer;
    }
```

This may produce a NullPointerException if your list contains a null, by simply putting a if check you can prevent it.

```
    for (Integer integer : ptAr) {
        if (null != integer) {
            sum += integer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this. I think my issue was with something else in my code, I just got it working.

Comment: If you solved your problem and your problem was entirely due to reason other than mentioned here then you should delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is fine. As Manmohan says, you might not have initialized the variable "sum". Check for errors like.

```
variable sum might not have been initialized
```